# C# Playing a flash video causes an error with wmode=direct

Tags: c#, winforms, flash, memory, wmode

I'm trying to play a flash movie inside of my C# window forms application, everything goes well and I can successfully load my .swf files.

However one of my flash files will not work as it requires **wmode=direct**

The moment that I change wmode to direct, I get this error:
***"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."***

This error only occurs when I change the wmode to direct, I've looked around but I haven't found a way to resolve this problem.

Here's my code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    axShockwaveFlash1.WMode = "Direct";
    axShockwaveFlash1.LoadMovie(0, swf_location);
    axShockwaveFlash1.Play();
}
```

How do I stop this error and have my application work correctly?
Any hints or help would be much appreciated

Comment: I'm also suffering with this. It seemed to occur after Windows update KB2961887

Comment: and also KB2957151 and KB2942844

Answer (score 0):

This issue is now resolved in flash player 14:

https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3768778